# Tensor Product and its details

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, tensors

I'm having a tough time trying to understand tensor product and how to compute it. I don't know what to do when I have $\alpha\in V^*$, $\vec v\in V$ and I want to compute $\alpha\otimes\vec v$ or $\vec v\otimes\alpha$... For example, if I have $\alpha = (e^3-4e^1)$ and $\vec v = (-2\vec e_1+\vec e_3)$, $\alpha\otimes\vec v$ and $\vec v\otimes\alpha$ look like what?

The definition that my professor has taught me is this:
given $\alpha,\beta\in V^*$ and $\vec u,\vec v\in V$ we have $(\alpha\otimes\beta)(\vec u,\vec v)\doteq \alpha(\vec u)\beta(\vec v)$. Thank you very much, folks.

Comment: There are several definitions of the "tensor" product that will make $\alpha \times v$ look (at least superficially) very different.  It would help us if you could write the definition that you're using, or at least point the textbook that you're using.

Comment: I meant to write $\alpha \otimes v$, of course.  Please remember that you can [edit] your question to add details.

Comment: Thank you! I've forgotten to edit my question!!

Comment: Why has somebody downvoted this question (I have upvoted it) ? Caue Evangelista is a newcomer, that has tried to her best to explain her problem.

Comment: Thank very much for your kind words JeanMarie, I really don't understand this type of thing as well...

Comment: @Caue don't let this keep you from asking stuff and enjoying this site. I'll try to help you understand, see my answer below.

Comment: Have a look at (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) which shows that, with respect to canonical bases, we can think about tensor products as  products of line and columns vectors or columns by line vectors (i.e. matrices)..

Answer (score 1):

The definition you wrote is for the tensor product of two linear functionals. You can consider the tensor product of a linear functional with a vector by "plugging in what makes sense", that is: $$(\alpha \otimes v)(w, \beta) \doteq \alpha(w)\beta(v),$$and so on. What you can do for now is write that as combination of "basic" tensors, using bilinearity of $\otimes$, as in: $$\begin{align} \alpha \otimes v &= (e^3 - 4e^1)\otimes(-2e_1+e_3)\\ &= -2 e^3\otimes e_1 + e^3\otimes e_3 + 8e^1\otimes e_1 - 4 e^1\otimes e_3.\end{align}$$If $f = f_i e^i$ and $w = w^j e_j$, you can see how $\alpha \otimes v$ acts explicitly by the above formula: $$(\alpha \otimes v)(w,f) = -2w^3f_1 + w^3f_3 + 8f^1w_1 - 4f^1w_3.$$

Comment: Thank you soo much Ivo! I thought earlier that maybe $\alpha$$\otimes$$\vec v$ is done this way but I was not sure! Seriously, thank you so much! My best wishes!

Comment: By the way, you don't need to use all these dollars \$ when typing mathjax here. See my edit to your question.

Comment: Oh, it's much more easy to read in your way! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Probably you are using for aeV* and veV that aoxv is the bilinear form on VxV* where v acts on b* in V* by point evaluation - v (b*) = b*(v) (thus identifying V** with V so aoxv(w,b*) = a(w)b*(v) .This works as long as V is finite dimensional .Hope that helps .What book are you using ?

Comment: I'm using the Arfken's book "Mathematical Methods for Physicists"